# jQuery script freezes half way

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a jQuery script that uses an Ajax call to pull data from a database for about 10 different html tables. The script is repeatedly looped with a 1 minute interval and all data is retrieved from the MySQL database within 5 seconds.

9 out of 10 runs the script finishes and all tables are updated. But that 1 time the script freezes half way and only refreshes 6 or 7 tables. I then refresh the full page to get up-to-date data.

Using the JavaScript console I've managed to analyze where the script freezes and noticed that it freezes near the end, after retrieving most of the data except for 1 or 2 tables.
Since Ajax handles the requests asynchronously it's not always the same data that breaks the script.

My first thought was that either Apache or the MySQL database gets too many requests and the PHP script doesn't return data, freezing the jQuery script.

At this point the webpage is only used by about 4 people. But in the future as much as 50 people will most likely use it and I'm afraid that this much requests might break the entire site.

Here's part of the console log for 1 run:

```
"[15:01:44.283] start" refresh.js:50
"[15:01:44.289] refresh data: timeframe" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.292] refresh data: tickets_agent" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.296] refresh data: tickets_type" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.298] refresh data: tickets_status" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.299] refresh data: tickets_prio" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.300] refresh data: tickets_critical" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.302] refresh data: tickets_high" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.302] refresh data: tickets_resolved_agent" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.303] refresh data: tickets_resolved_group" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.304] refresh data: tickets_new" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.305] refresh data: changes_group" refresh.js:57
"[15:01:44.476] update data: timeframe" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:44.656] update data: tickets_critical" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:44.689] update data: tickets_high" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:44.936] update data: tickets_prio" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:44.938] update data: tickets_resolved_group" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:44.965] update data: tickets_resolved_agent" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:45.106] update data: changes_group" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:45.174] update data: tickets_status" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:45.179] update data: tickets_new" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:46.538] update data: tickets_type" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:47.114] update data: tickets_agent" refresh.js:66
"[15:01:47.257] finish" refresh.js:74
```

As you can see the script starts at 15:01:44 and finishes at 15:01:47. So it takes about 4 seconds to pull all the required data from the database - *where `refresh data` = "pull data from SQL database" and `update data` = "update the html table"* - and it doesn't always `update` in the same order it `refresh`-es. Sometimes it freezes after `update data: changes_group`, sometimes it freezes after `update data: tickets_status`.

What else can I do to find the reason why the script freezes, preventing subsequent requests and requiring the user to reload the entire page?

=== update: here's the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var seconds = 60;
    var timeout = seconds * 1000;
    var items = [ 'timeframe', 
                  'tickets_agent', 
                  'tickets_type', 
                  'tickets_status', 
                  'tickets_prio', 
                  'tickets_critical', 
                  'tickets_high', 
                  'tickets_resolved_agent',
                  'tickets_resolved_group',
                  'tickets_new',
                  'changes_group'];

    load();

    $(".datepick").change(function() {
        process();
    });

    $("#datepickerReset").click(function() {
        process();
    });

    function getNow() {
        var d = new Date();
        var h = ("0"+d.getHours()).slice(-2);
        var m = ("0"+d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
        var s = ("0"+d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
        var ms = d.getMilliseconds();

        var t = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "." + ms;
        var ts = "[" + t + "] ";
        return ts;
    }

    function load() {
        $("#progressbar").animate({ width: "100%" }, timeout, "linear", function() {
            process();
        });
    };

    function process() {
        var timestamp = getNow();
        console.log(timestamp + "start");

        var n = items.length;
        $("#progressbar").stop().css({ width: "0" });
        $("#loading").fadeIn(200);
        $.each( items, function( key, item ) {
            var timestamp = getNow();
            console.log(timestamp + "refresh data: " + item);
            $.ajax({
                url: "view/jquery/refresh.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { item : item },
                dataType: "html"
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                var timestamp = getNow();
                console.log(timestamp + "update data: " + item);
                $("#" + item).animate({ opacity: "0.4" }, 100).promise().done(function() {
                    $("#" + item).html(data).animate({ opacity: "1" }, 100);
                    n -= 1;

                if (n === 0) {
                    $("#loading").fadeOut(200);
                    var timestamp = getNow();
                    console.log(timestamp + "finish");
                    load();
                };
                });
            });
        });
    };
});
```

*ps: I have considered using `async: false` in the Ajax call, but then the console shows a warning about the option being depricated. And it makes the whole script take nearly 10 seconds longer to complete.*

Comment: is this on a shared hosting server?

Comment: No, the website is running on a dedicated server (Win 2k8 R2 SP1, 4GB RAM, Dual 2.1 GHz Intel Xeon). It runs WAMP (64-bit).
However, the database with the data being retrieved is on a dedicated MS-SQL database server. And that data is also retrieved by various clients (up to 50 or so) using a different application.

Comment: ok, though maybe some sort of dos/frequent post lock out was taking place. can you show the code that does the posts/http requests??

Comment: Do you have a console log for a failed run? Since the browser runs your JS single-threaded, getting *any* uncaught error will result in no subsequent JS being executed (including async calls) and thus *"freeze"*

Comment: Have you considered that the request may be processing that long? Can you check that on the back end?

Comment: I have considered that the request may take long to process, but that doesn't explain why it only happens to freeze at random intervals. Sometimes it runs for 15 minutes handling 15 repetitions before freezing once, sometimes it runs for 15 minutes but needs 10 full page reloads.

Comment: In addition to `.done()` add a `.fail()` condition to see if you are missing any errors (i.e. timeouts).

Comment: `.fail()` added...waiting for the moment it freezes. I hope it shows some useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing `$("#" + item).animate({ opacity: "0.4" }, 100).promise().done(` and moving this opacity animation above the `$.ajax` call the script doesn't freeze anymore.
So apparently the opacity animation inside the `.done` was causing the problem.